# Barplot/line plot on same plot, but different axis and line plot in front of barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using pandas to plot some data.

If I plot this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 200, 150, 175],
                   'b': [430, 30, 20, 10]})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
df['b'].plot(kind='bar', color='y')
df['a'].plot(kind='line', marker='d')
```

Everything plots fine.

[image: GoodGraph]

If I plot the bar axis on the secondary axis, the bar plot will be in front of the line plots, obstructing the lines from being viewed, like this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 200, 150, 175],
                   'b': [430, 30, 20, 10]})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
df['b'].plot(kind='bar', color='y', secondary_y=True)
df['a'].plot(kind='line', marker='d')
```

[image: SadGraph]

How do I make a bar plot/line plot where...

- Using pandas/matplotlib
- Bar plot is on secondary axis and line chart is on primary axis
- Line plots are in front of the bar plot

Comment: I assume that the `plot()` function of a `Dataframe` also has the `zorder` keyword; you could try setting that to some high value in your second example.

Comment: Hmm... Hadn't thought of that. But it still doesn't seem like it works. I can tell that it works when both are plotted on the left y-axis, but the one plotted on the right y-axis is always on top. I would really prefer to have bars on the right y axis, so my boss sees the same thing he's always seen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could put line on primary axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 200, 150, 175],
                   'b': [430, 30, 20, 10]})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
df['b'].plot(kind='bar', color='y')
df['a'].plot(kind='line', marker='d', secondary_y=True)
```

[image]

Or, create two axes `ax1` and `ax2` with [`twinx()`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 200, 150, 175],
                   'b': [430, 30, 20, 10]})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df['b'].plot(kind='bar', color='y', ax=ax1)
df['a'].plot(kind='line', marker='d', ax=ax2)
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
```

[image]