# two plots from pandas dataframe with different vertical axes on the same figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i'm trying to plot in python a line plot and a bar plot on the same figure using data from pandas dataframe. i manage to get two axes on the plot and the legend displays two entries, but the first of the plots is not present.

here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ax1 = data[["timestamp", "polarity"]].plot(x="timestamp", kind="bar")
ax1.set_xticks(data["timestamp"].values)
ax1.set_ylabel("polarity")
ax1.set_xlabel("year")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
data[["timestamp", "revenue"]].plot(x="timestamp", linestyle="-", marker="o", ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel("revenue")

plt.show()
```

and this is the plot that i get:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvuoU.png)

when i reverse the order in which i plot, i get the following plot:

[plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3muJt.png)

how do i make the plots appear on the same figure?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't really read your code, but this link might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38132706/2336654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = pd.date_range(start='2016-07-15',periods=50,freq='D')
y1 = np.sin(np.linspace(0,50))
y2 = np.cos(np.linspace(0,0.3))
data = pd.DataFrame({'y1':y1,'y2':y2,'x':x})
data.set_index('x')
```

So here is a dataframe with a bunch of points.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.bar(data.index,data['y1'],color='w')   

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(data.index,data['y2'],'k-')

fig.show()
```

That will give you a bar graph with a line over it, each on a separate y axis but on the same figure. 
[image: a bar graph with a line over it, with separate y axes]